# how to run a method when class is initialized in dart

Tags: dart

In python you can run a simple function inside of a `__init__` method like this:

```py
class AuthError:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        print(self.message)
```

how can I do this in dart? (I'm fairly new to dart and flutter)

```
class AuthError {
  final String message;
  MyExample(this.message); // <-- how do I e.g. print message when AuthError is initialized?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a constructor to you class. The constructor should be named the same as the class it is part of:

```
class AuthError {
  final String message;

  AuthError(this.message) {
    print('AuthError is initialized');
  }
}

void main() {
  AuthError('string'); // AuthError is initialized
}
```

Read more about here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Comment: Haha! Can't believe I didn't think of that! Thanks!