# Flutter Constructor Default Value

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

In the Workout class below, I'd like to initialize avgCalorieBurn to be the average of calorie burn for each exercise inside that class. Is there a way to do this?

```
class Wourkout {
  List<Exercise> exercises;
  int? avgCalorieBurn;

  Wourkout({required this.exercises, this.avgCalorieBurn});
}

class Exercise {
  int calorieBurn;
  Exercise({required this.calorieBurn});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to the constructor. As stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481793/13772418). Also, typo in Wourkourt => Workout

```
class Workout {
  List<Exercise> exercises;
  int? avgCalorieBurn; // or late int avgCalorieBurn;

  Workout({required this.exercises}) {
    int sum = 0;
    exercises.forEach((exercice) {
      sum += exercice.calorieBurn;
    });
    avgCalorieBurn = sum ~/ exercises.length; // Truncated integer division
  }
}

class Exercise {
  int calorieBurn;
  Exercise({required this.calorieBurn});
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's it!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Wourkout {
  List<Exercise> exercises;
  double? avgCalorieBurn;

  Wourkout({required this.exercises}) 
    : avgCalorieBurn = exercises.length  == 0 
                     ? null
                     : exercises.map((e) => e.calorieBurn).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / exercises.length;
}

class Exercise {
  int calorieBurn;
  Exercise({required this.calorieBurn});
}
```

I changed the average to a double, because that is what you get as the average between integers.